# calling method that was undefined in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, monkeypatching

using external API that has defined as special class where almost all standard methods are undefined to use for building xml. Where `#method_missing` is responsible to generate elements based on the missing method name called over the object.

Basically in class body there is something to the effect of:

```
undef_method :send
```

Now I want to programatically call method by name. I guess I can use `eval "obj.#{something}"` but I really don't like `eval`.
I was thinking there must be some dark-side technique to revert the undefining of method `#send` so I can alias it to `#__send__` and undefine it again. That way I can happily call methods by name without eval. e.g. `obj.__send__(:something, params)`.

So my question is how do I use monkey patching to revert the `#send` method. I can't find anything to that effect. Even can't find anybody asking about it either.

UPDATE: My original problem was non-problem because there is a method `#__send__` anyway, I knew only about `#send`. The other part of the question was how to restore an undefined method. With help of @philomory asnwer here's what I've got:

```
[46] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)> class A
[46] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)*   def gah
[46] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)*     puts "gah"
[46] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)*   end  
[46] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)* end  
=> :gah
[49] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)> class C < A
[49] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)*   undef_method :gah
[49] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)* end  
=> C
[50] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)> C.new.gah
NoMethodError: undefined method `gah' for #<C:0x000000070d7918>
[57] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)> class C
[57] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)*   define_method :fff , A.instance_method(:gah)
[57] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)* end  
=> :fff
[58] pry(#<CucuShift::DefaultWorld>)> C.new.fff
gah
```

Comment: I'm confused - why can't you call __send__ ?

Comment: Stupid formatting - I meant `__send__`

Comment: @FrederickCheung, because I never knew there is a `#__send__` method. I only knew `#send`. I guess that explains the negative question rating.. ruby really bad documentation, anyway, thank you

Comment: Ruby has amazing documentation, you just have to actually look.

Comment: @13aal, I guess you never looked at documentation of other languages like java for example. Ruby is the lang that for me has the least clearly defined behavior in documentation compared to other languages I've used. Fortunately it's vast popularity makes most topics well covered in blogs and forums. 
btw looking at number of question I've asked on the site, it would appear I'm actually very smart having only a few questions... provided your assertion was correct and I don't do research prior asking.

Comment: @akostadinov what does your intelligence or lack of have anything to Dow with asking this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dark magic you are looking for is the [UnboundMethod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/UnboundMethod.html) class. Use it like this (assuming `obj` is your builder API object):

```
send_method = BasicObject.instance_method(:__send__)
bound_method = send_method.bind(obj)
bound_method.call(:method_you_are_calling_dynamically,*arguments)
```

Of course, depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you could just get the specific method you want and bind it directly, like

```
id_method = BasicObject.intance_method(:__id__)
bound_method = id_method.bind(obj)
bound_method.call
```

Or, if the builder class is using `method_missing` and you just want to dynamically dispatch to that, you don't need `send` or anything like it at all, just call `obj.method_missing(:my_dynamic_method_name)`

---

UPDATE:

It's worth noting that you should not need to alias `send` to `__send__` as `__send__` is already provided as part of BasicObject and it is very unusual to un-define it. Though I suppose if you are using an earlier version of Ruby without BasicObject and `__send__` you do it this way:

```
def obj.__send__(*args,&blk)
  Object.instance_method(:send).bind(self).call(*args,&blk)
end
```

Comment: hmm, never knew there is a `#__send__` method out of the box. Always used the `#send` method which does the same. my bad!

Comment: FYI I don't see `BasicObject.instance_method(:__send__)` working on ruby 2.2, would be useful to fix if you can. Update to answer works though so marking as solution.

Comment: I just tried it on 2.2.2 and it worked fine for me. What error are you seeing? Note that the first methods I wrote don't give you an actually method called `send` or `__send__` back; they are what you do _instead_ of directly writing `obj.send` or `obj.__send__`.

Comment: I think I maybe got a typo before. It is indeed working. I still don't see how to revert a method into the class itself as an instance method though. I have my immediate problem solves as I say above but interesting to know how to actually restore the method.

Comment: Huh, got it, will update my question. Thanks a lot, very useful.

Comment: Glad to help. Note that the method you added to your question, using `define_method`, will not work if the class you are working with has undef-ed `define_method` (though, usually this will not be a problem, as people usually only `undef` instance methods, not class methods). That said, the method I showed (using `def` instead of `define_method`) will _always_ work (because def is a language keyword and cannot be overruled), but it does come with a small performance penalty (not because `define_method` is faster, but because my version calls `instance_method`, `bind` and `call` on every call).